# Microsoft chatbot c#. Remove tags

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

Is it possible to remove these `Bot message` and `User message` tags from the chat window?

[image: Chatbot C# remove tags]

Comment: We can't answer your question if you don't show us your code.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Usually you wouldn't run it in an emulator and *real* channels like Skype don't show them anyways, do they?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer yes you are right i will be running it in real channels but i was just curious to know if it is possible to remove it in emulator as well.

Comment: @gopaljoshi If you didn't find anything in the settings then I'm guessing your only option is Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to do some more research on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely possible in the emulator.  The emulator is an open source project which you can customize whoever you see fit for your needs.  To do this you would need to do a custom build of the emulator.  You can find the repository here to get started https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason.